# XML parse using powershell gives 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed' error

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm trying to parse the below xml using powershell. Below is my code, the results giving

> Exception calling "SelectSingleNode" with "1" argument(s): "Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

How to parse this XML using powershell script?

Code:

```
$webConfig = "Rubyconf.config"
$XmlObj = New-Object XML
$XmlObj.Load($webConfig)
$ScheduleMaintenance = 'Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring'
$Xmlnode = $XmlObj.SelectSingleNode($ScheduleMaintenance)
Write-Output $Xmlnode
```

I'm trying to set the "MaximumCheckForScheduleAttempts" value as 10. Some one can help me on this please?

XML File

```
<RubySettings xmlns="http://schemasxxxxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Settings xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:Key>LiveMaximumNumberParallelModelExecutions</a:Key>
            <a:Value>7</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>        
        <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:Key>ModelCompilationTimeout</a:Key>
            <a:Value>00:02:00.0000000</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:Key>MaximumCheckForScheduleAttempts</a:Key>
            <a:Value>5</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:Key>ExternalCalloutPermitted</a:Key>
            <a:Value>true</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
        <a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
            <a:Key>ExternalCalloutTimeout</a:Key>
            <a:Value>00:00:00.2000000</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    </Settings>
<lastChanged>2019-12-02T15:36:48.513Z</lastChanged>
</DpoSettings>
```

Comment: Note - your xml is invalid - the final ```</DpoSettings>``` should match the opening ```<RubySettings>```. One or the other needs to be changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got a few problems.

- The first is a simple typo in your sample xml - your closing `</DpoSettings>` doesn't match your opening `<RubySettings>`.
- The second problem is that namespace prefixes defined in an xml document (e.g. the `a` prefix in the `xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"` from your `<Settings>` element) don't get imported into your code. In other words, the `a:` in your `a:KeyValueOfstringstring` doesn't have any meaning in your XPath queries unless you do a bit of extra work to re-define the `a:` prefix in your code.
- Third, your XPath query `Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring`is slightly wonky

### Invalid xml

This one's an easy fix - if we assume the closing element should be `</RubySettings>` we can get past this and then we can reproduce the error you've reported.

```xml
<RubySettings xmlns="http://schemasxxxxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</DpoSettings>
```

becomes

```xml
<RubySettings xmlns="http://schemasxxxxxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</RubySettings>
```

### Namespace prefixes

To fix the second issue (and your error message), what you need to do is create an [XmlNamespaceManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager?view=netframework-4.8) to define your own namespace prefixes, which might (or might not match) the ones in the original xml document, and then use those prefixes in your XPath query:

```bsh
$webConfig = "Rubyconf.config"
$XmlObj = New-Object XML
$XmlObj.Load($webConfig)

# create namespace prefixes
$nametable = new-object System.Xml.NameTable;
$nsmgr = new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($nametable);
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemasxxxxxx");
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");

# now we can use x: and a:
$ScheduleMaintenance = 'x:RubySettings/x:Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring'

# note the $nsmgr parameter which maps "a:" in the xpath query to the actual namespace
# "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" in the xml document
$Xmlnode = $XmlObj.SelectSingleNode($ScheduleMaintenance, $nsmgr)

Write-Output $Xmlnode

# Key                                      Value
# ---                                      -----
# LiveMaximumNumberParallelModelExecutions 7
```

Note the prefix name `a` matches the one in your original xml document but we could just as easily have said something like:

```bsh
...
$nametable = new-object System.Xml.NameTable;
$nsmgr = new-object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($nametable);
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("default", "http://schemasxxxxxx");
$nsmgr.AddNamespace("arrays", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays");

$ScheduleMaintenance = 'default:RubySettings/default:Settings/arrays:KeyValueOfstringstring'
...
```

and as long as the prefix in the XPath string matches the one in the XmlNamespaceManager things will work just fine.

Now that we've got all of that working, we can refine the XPath query to select the node we're actually interested in.

### XPath query

Note - the code above also fixes one part of the XPath issue - i.e. you need to include the root `RubySettings` in the XPath in order to find the `Settings` node, and use the appropriate prefixes.

That is:

```bsh
$ScheduleMaintenance = 'x:RubySettings/x:Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring'
```

At this point, you could do something clever with XPath to find the single node with a child `Key` element with text `MaximumCheckForScheduleAttempts`:

```bsh
$ScheduleMaintenance = "x:RubySettings/x:Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring/a:Key[text()='MaximumCheckForScheduleAttempts']/.."
```

but it's probably easier to just use PowerShell's `where-object` on all the `a:KeyValueOfstringstring` nodes:

```bsh
$ScheduleMaintenance = "x:RubySettings/x:Settings/a:KeyValueOfstringstring"
$Xmlnodes = $XmlObj.SelectNodes($ScheduleMaintenance, $nsmgr)
$Xmlnode = $xmlnodes | where-object { $_.Key -eq "MaximumCheckForScheduleAttempts" }
```

Note - we're using `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode` and then using PowerShell to filter the results.

### Updating values

Finally you can update the value of the node:

```bsh
$Xmlnode.Value = "10" # value has to be a string
```

and then save the xml document

```bsh
$XmlObj.Save($newFilename)
```

Hope this helps.